# Extracting Output parameters vs result set in Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I was looking into SpringJdbc code and noticed that, when spring wants to extract the result from output parameters, it directly uses the type unsafe method `getObject(int index)`:

[`Object out = cs.getObject(sqlColIndex);`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L1238)

However for extracting Result from Result set, they [wrote more code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/support/JdbcUtils.java#L142) to try finding out the exact type:

```
public static Object getResultSetValue(ResultSet rs, int index, Class<?> requiredType) throws SQLException {
    if (requiredType == null) {
        return getResultSetValue(rs, index);
    }

    Object value;

    // Explicitly extract typed value, as far as possible.
    if (String.class == requiredType) {
        return rs.getString(index);
    }
    else if (boolean.class == requiredType || Boolean.class == requiredType) {
        value = rs.getBoolean(index);
    }
    else if (byte.class == requiredType || Byte.class == requiredType) {
......
.....
```

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

After searching in that subject, I realized that;

May be because of the the lack of a Metadata object the provides information about parameter names.

As passing the output parameter names to be registered to the stored procedure is optional (you can register output parameter by index), and the ParameterMetaData object returned from the callable statement doesn't return the names of the output parameters.

Spring; however fill a map of parameter name (it asks the user to set when creating the output parameter using its-own API) and the parameter value.